# Alternative to memset

Tags: c, initialization, memset

I want to initialize an array of struct, however the second parameter of memset() takes an int. Is there another the function that does the same but with a (void *) has 2nd parameter? 
I thought of memcpy() but it doesn't set the value in the entire array. Any idea?

the struct:

```
typedef struct {
    int x;
    int y;
    char *data;
} my_stuff;
```

The code:

```
my_stuff my_array[];
my_array = malloc(MAX * sizeof(my_stuff));

my_stuff *tmp;
tmp->x = -1;
tmp->y = 1;
strcpy(tmp->data = "Initial state");

memset(my_array, tmp, sizeof(my_array));
```

Comment: What exactly do you need a `void*` for? `memset` on a struct with a non-zero parameter is rather rare...

Comment: well I'm just looking for a function that doesn't take an int as the 2nd parameter. That way I can pass my struct easily as a parameter. I know I can do it with a for loop but I wanted to find a more intuitive way to initialize the array.

Comment: Ah I see... unfortunately there's nothing that does this for you in C. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`memset()` sets the value of each byte. There's no problem typecasting a pointer to an integer (the second parameter). The main problem is that it will be bigger than a byte.

I'm not aware of any version of `memset()` that copies more than byte values. I would create a simple loop for this.

Also note that there would be some additional problems with your code, had it worked. For one thing, `sizeof(my_array)` returns the total number of bytes in the data structure and not the number of elements. Also, your code would've just copied the pointer. You need to actually copy the data it points to since the target is not pointers--it's actual structures.

Comment: There is `wmemset`, but the unit size is `wchar_t` which is stupidly 16-bit on Windows and 32-bit everywhere else...

Comment: @R..: Yes, I forgot about `wmemset()`. But, yeah, it was intended more for characters than integers. Even at 32-bits, it would fall short for copying pointers on 64-bit systems.

Answer (score 4):

There isn't a standard function for this - you will just need to call `memcpy()` in a loop:

```
my_stuff *my_array = malloc(MAX * sizeof(my_stuff));
my_stuff tmp;
size_t i;

tmp.x = -1;
tmp.y = 1;
tmp.data = "Initial state";

for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    memcpy(&my_array[i], &tmp, sizeof tmp);
```

Note that you can't `strcpy()` into `tmp.data`, because that's just a dangling pointer with no memory allocated.

Comment: +1 However my preference is to declare `tmp` as constant: `const my_stuff tmp = { -1, 1, "Initial state" };`

Comment: @Ben: Yes - and it's even better with C99 designated initializers (and you should also make it `static`).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use memset() in this case. You should use memcpy(). Just try this out:
1. malloc your array
2. initialize the first element of the array
3. copy the first element to all the elements

```
/* step 1 */
my_stuff *my_array = malloc(MAX * sizeof(my_stuff));
int i;

/* step 2 */
my_array[0].x = -1;
my_array[0].y = 1;
my_array[0].data = "Initial state";

/* step 3 */
for (i = 1; i < MAX; i++)
    memcpy(&my_array[i], &my_array[0], sizeof(my_array[0]));
```